# Oracle SQL Developer How to export via a command line the result of a SQL script?

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my first question on StackOverflow (but not the first question I asked to myself on Oracle SQL Developer :p)

My needs :

I first tried to do all my works exclusively on Oracle SQL Dev but it asks to much ressources to be done.

In consequences, I decided to only export all the data I need and then import all in R and do my work on it.
Finally, it takes about 2 minutes to do the job :D

My problem is :
I run about 10 different SQL script which are really simple. Please find below two of them :

```
select japolip_wnupo wnupo,japolip_socpo socpo,japolip_jasccdp_winag winag,japolip_wnpro wnpro,jaagenp_ainag,jaagenp_nomag
from sunapicf.japolip japolip
left join sunapicf.jaagenp jaagenp on jaagenp_winag = japolip_jasccdp_winag
;
```

```
select distinct socpr socpo,jaagenp.jaagenp_winag winag,JACRCFP.JACRCFP_wnpro wnpro,jaagenp_ainag,jaagenp_nomag
from sunapicp.JACRCFP JACRCFP
left join 
(
select japrodp_wnpro,socpr
from sunapicp.japrodp japrodp
cross join xmltable('//JAPRODP' passing xmltype(japrodp.ficxml) columns SOCPR)
) japrodp on japrodp.japrodp_wnpro = JACRCFP.JACRCFP_wnpro
left join sunapicf.jaagenp jaagenp on jaagenp.jaagenp_winag = jacrcfp.jacrcfp_winit
;
```

Then I have to launch the Export function for every results, change the formatting and the type of file to be delivered to .dsv (just to have the right comma :D), and also change the folder directory and the name.

It is too much repetitive and can generate some mistakes.

That's why I would like to add a command line where I would specify the folder directory, the name, the formatting and what so ever.

Do you have any information about that ?

Thank you very much.

I did not try anything because I don't have any idea to try.

I tried to connect R to Oracle but I guess I have to pay for it (and the company does not want to :D).

Comment: If you look in the preferences, in Tools->Preferences->Database->Utilities->Export, you can set defaults for some of the things you're doing repetitively. You could also look at [the SQLcl command-line equivalent to SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl/sqlcl-faq.html), and its `set sqlformat` setting.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. I already set defaults but I have to to do modifications for about 20 files.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/sqlcl/) is definitely the way to go. Build a script (or set of scripts) that run all of the queries that you want to export data into CSV files. Below is an example script that will connect to the database, set formatting, generate the files then disconnect.

The script would get launched with a command like this:

```
sql /nolog @start_export.sql
```

**start_export.sql** example contents:

```sql
--Connect to the database
connect <username>/<password>@<TNSalias>

--Set format to CSV for results from SELECT statements
set sqlformat csv;
--Turn off the number of rows that get returned by the select
set feedback off;

--Create 1st report
spool report1.csv

select japolip_wnupo wnupo,japolip_socpo socpo,japolip_jasccdp_winag winag,japolip_wnpro wnpro,jaagenp_ainag,jaagenp_nomag
from sunapicf.japolip japolip
left join sunapicf.jaagenp jaagenp on jaagenp_winag = japolip_jasccdp_winag;

--Create 2nd report
spool report2.csv

select distinct socpr socpo,jaagenp.jaagenp_winag winag,JACRCFP.JACRCFP_wnpro wnpro,jaagenp_ainag,jaagenp_nomag
from sunapicp.JACRCFP JACRCFP
left join 
(
select japrodp_wnpro,socpr
from sunapicp.japrodp japrodp
cross join xmltable('//JAPRODP' passing xmltype(japrodp.ficxml) columns SOCPR)
) japrodp on japrodp.japrodp_wnpro = JACRCFP.JACRCFP_wnpro
left join sunapicf.jaagenp jaagenp on jaagenp.jaagenp_winag = jacrcfp.jacrcfp_winit;

--Disconnect
exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

I tried to launch the file SQL.exe but I don't have JRE and I don't don't have enough credentials to it.

May you explain me how to do use it with Jportable for example ? I installed jdk with the .zip but I have the same message. Maybe there is a link with the JAVA_HOME variable that I can't change.

What can I do ? Thanks

Comment: Setting the JAVA_HOME is not required. Make sure that java is in your Path environment variable.

Comment: Thank you ! I installed JAVA and no problem then to launch SQLcl !

Where would the start_export.sql file be stored ? And what should I specify to indicate the folder where the file is stored ?

Comment: `start_export.sql` can be put in any directory. The sample code assumes that your terminal is in the same directory as the file. If it is not, then you can specify the full path to `start_export.sql`